# Concurrent release versions on Repos + ClickOnce, what to anticipate?

Tags: deployment, release-management

I publish COM addins for Office via ClickOnce.
At the moment, I have only one main branch on the Repos tree (using Azure DevOps), and each time I publish, all the users are automatically updated.

Now, what if I release a substantial update - which would involve a change in a work flow - and one of the teams wishes not to roll the update? (could be for many reasons such as "we are in the middle to sending something out and no time for learning curve right now", to "the new update does not provide a feature we loved")
I can implement this, but what if then I have to undertake a critical-compulsory fix?

I am thinking of allowing several major versions to be available in parallel, whilst within each of them a minor version update would be compulsory.
That is, going from 1.2 to 2.0 would be optional, but going from either 1.2 to 1.3 or 2.0 to 2.1 would be compulsory. This way, everyone is happy.

Well, I hope.. Because I never worked on distinct Repos branches. Also, not sure how ClickOnce might like this..

Any tips or warnings for potential challenges would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: No such thing as compulsory in software unless you own the hardware and do the work yourself.

Comment: Did you tell Microsoft? :'D

Comment: More seriously, there are plenty of good reasons why you might want to force an update, starting with "API dependencies are migrating", or "all users of an organization need to run the same version so that they share compatible files". As soon as the updates do not alter the user experience, i.e. purely implementation-based, I do not see why this would be a Bad Thing (tm).

Comment: Microsoft is still patching XP. Don't ask me how I know. I'd rather not talk about it.

Comment: So the whole Win7 coming to an end thing is a lie! Just like the cake.. !

Comment: I thought we were debating the effectiveness of the concept of compulsory software not Microsoft's relationship with the truth. And what cake?

Comment: In Microsoft's generic Terms of Use (for example for VS2019), it is said : "You agree to receive these automatic updates without any additional notice. Updates may not include or support all existing software features, services, or peripheral devices."

Comment: Cake is here: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20cake%20is%20a%20lie

Comment: I agreed to receive them, not install them and reboot whenever they want me to. What do you think a registry editor is for? Sometimes I like to know my computer will just be quiet and do what I tell it to.

Comment: I think their approach is similar to what I'd like to do: major versions (e.g. VS2017 versus VS2019) are automatically updated, but features and workflows are barely touched between updates within a major version (that is, VS2017 build N to VS2017 build N+1). Changes in features and/or workflow are optional because you may decide to keep running VS2017 and never switch to 2019.
In any cases, this is not on topic: I am interested in implementation/maintenance details, rather than whether my users will like it or not.